# Windows Server 2008 r2 security against uploaded scripts

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have developed an asp.net application and windows desktop application system. My clients can upload images to asp.net application(only one folder). So if someone uploads a shell script and executes, one can take the other clients' database files. 
Asp.net application works under windows server 2008 r2(web server edition) OS and IIS 7.5.it has administrator rights for now. I don't have a domain and domain controller so i don't have advanced user rights management. And "applicationpoolidentiy" doesn't help(i even can't open page.). I thought maybe i can deny executing of uploaded scripts? Is it possible. Or are there any better ways to secure server from uploaded scripts?

Comment: *cough*  http://serverfault.com *cough*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your upload page to reject all files with extensions that aren't images using an extension whitelist.

For additional security, you should configure IIS to not execute scripts in that directory.

Comment: yes but if someone uploads a file with bmp or png extension instead of aspx,asp extension or just uploads a file within shell code, iis still execute that.

Comment: @ŞafakKapçı: Wrong.  IIS executes files based on extensions, not contents.

Comment: thank you @SLaks. i will configure folder for user from file options.